# How to stage only part of a new file with git?

Tags: git

I **love** *git add --interactive*. It is now part of my daily workflow.

The problem seems that it does not work with untracked files. What I want to do is track a new file, but only add part of it, i.e. some parts of this new file are not yet ready to be staged.

For example, with git add -i, I can chose the patch option and even edit individual hunks in order to stage parts of the new code, leaving debug code comments unstaged. I love working this way because it makes it obvious which places of the mega patch I am currently working on still need work.

Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to do the same with an untracked file. Either I stage the whole file, or nothing. The workaround I have been using is staging or even committing a new file when it is empty, and then staging individual changes in the usual way. But this solution feels like a dirty hack and when I forget, or change my mind, it creates more troubles than there should be.

So the question is: How to stage only part of a new file, so that this new file gets tracked but leaving the whole or parts of its content unstaged?

Answer (score 512, accepted):

Whoa, all that `update-index` and `hash-object` business seems overly complicated.  How about this instead:

```
git add -N new_file
git add -i  # or 'git add -p' if you prefer
```

From `git help add`:

```
-N, --intent-to-add
    Record only the fact that the path will be added later.  An entry
    for the path is placed in the index with no content.  This is useful
    for, among other things, showing the unstaged content of such files
    with git diff and committing them with git commit -a.
```

Comment: ++1! due credit. I do trust a bit too much that I know these manpages by now .... `</shame>`

Comment: Well found. I should have scrolled the man page a bit further. Perhaps I should return Git Pro badge.

Comment: Wonder why git-gui doesn't use this internally to be able to stage lines from a new file.

Comment: Wonderful `-N` discovery, thanks! Though I'd prefer combining it with `-p` in that case. `gid add -N the_file` & `git add -p`. One should add that `-N` also works with `-A`

Comment: @Deiwin - you could add a [guitool] to your .gitconfig to do a "git add -N $FILENAME":

[guitool "Add with intent"]
        cmd = "git add -N $FILENAME"
        needsfile = yes
        noconsole = yes

Comment: `-N` did not work for me, however, `--intent-to-add` did.

Comment: I used to do it (`git add -N; git add -p`) before. But it is not working anymore (git 2.28.windows.1 here). `git add -p` do not show the e[dit]  alternative (it shows "(1/1) Stage addition [y,n,q,a,d,?]?").

Answer (score 9):

```
git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644 $(git hash-object -w /dev/null) newfile
git add --interactive newfile
```

Simple demo:

```
mkdir /tmp/demo
cd /tmp/demo
git init .

echo hello > newfile
git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644 $(git hash-object -w /dev/null) newfile
```

- <sub>**Hint** If you're sure the 'empty' blob already exists in your git object database, you could hardcode the hash `e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391` instead. I don't recommend doing that_</sub>
- <sub>**Hint** If you're on Windows, you probably can just use `NUL:` instead of `/dev/null`. Otherwise, use something like `echo -n '' | git hash-object --stdin -w`</sub>

Now the index will contain `newfile` as the empty blob, and the empty blob has been entered into the object database if it didn't exist yet:

```
$ find .git/objects/ -type f 
.git/objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391

$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   newfile
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   newfile
#

$ git diff
diff --git a/newfile b/newfile
index e69de29..ce01362 100644
--- a/newfile
+++ b/newfile
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+hello
```

This should be precisely what you want. May I also recommend the vim fugitive plugin for very intelligent index management (see [Better git add -p?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851461/better-git-add-p/5851626#5851626))

Comment: This seems to work well. I've aliased it to "stage-empty-file" as it's a bit complex to remember.

Comment: @dave1010: Glad that it helped! _Yeah I thought about adding an alias, but I didn't know how you'd expect to handle e.g. wildcards or multiple filename arguments in general. So I opted not to_

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do this (and imho interactive staging in general) is `git gui`. It comes bundled with git and should work on almost all platforms that are supported by git.

Simply run `git gui` and a gui will open that allows staging and unstaging hunks and even single lines of tracked and untracked files.

[image: Git Gui screenshot]

Comment: This is a creative answer and sometimes it's very, very useful.

Comment: Just a note that not all git distributions include `git gui`. In Debian, for example, it is in a separate package called 'git-gui'.

Comment: Have been looking (not hard enough) for this feature for years, this is a life changer

Comment: For me the staging of single lines of untracked files in `git gui` has never worked. In fact, it [disables these menu options](http://i.imgur.com/PhSHm7D.png).

Comment: @Deiwin I must actually have missed this in the question – my screenshot shows an already tracked file. If you want to use `git gui` for a new file, you have to run `git add -N new_file` first – see Richard Hansen‘s answer.

Comment: @Chronial, I'm aware off the `--intend-to-add` *trick*, but this also has its limitations. With it, you can stage single lines in `git gui`, but you can't unstage single lines.

Comment: git gui is not available on all systems.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** this doesn't seem to be working now. I'm sure it was before (on git 1.7.1). In case it doesn't work, I suggest staging `/dev/null` as sehe suggests above:

```
git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644 $(git hash-object -w /dev/null) newfile
```

If you're on Windows (without `/dev/null`) then you can replace it with the path to an empty file.

**Original answer**

You want

```
git add -p # (or --patch)
```

This adds untracked files for me. From the man page:

> Interactively choose hunks of patch
>   between the index and the work tree
>   and add them to the index. This gives
>   the user a chance to review the
>   difference before adding modified
>   contents to the index.
>
> This effectively runs add
>   --interactive, but bypasses the initial command menu and directly
>   jumps to the patch subcommand. See
>   “Interactive mode” for details.

Comment: However interesting, it doesn't work for me (git 1.7.4); `git add -p newfile` doesn't work at all (nu effect) and `git add --interactive` '[a]dd untracked' has the effect that `git add newfile` has; **Edit** also checked with git 1.7.5.3; no dice

Comment: Good hint for Windows, added hints for that in my answer. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record of another possibility:
I use

```
git add -N file
git add -p file
```

And then you can stage hunks, or edit them in place.

Comment: This answer says the same as the accepted answer, that dates back to 2011. Downvote.

Comment: The accepted answer combines `add -N` with `add -i`. I just added that `add -p` instead of `add -i` works, too.

Comment: Richard edited-in the `-p` comment 3 years after this answer. It's a fair game. +1