# is there a command in GIT that has the options of "git add -p" and "git checkout -p" COMBINED?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-add

I would like to issue *one* command that lets me interactively either ADD a hunk, DISCARD a hunk or leave the hunk unstaged...

Actually as I know of there is only:

`git add -p`: ADDs hunks interactively (or leave unstaged) 
`git checkout -p`: DISCARDS hunks interactively  (or leave unstaged)

Is there a command in GIT that has the options of "git add -p" and "git checkout -p" COMBINED ?

The answer to this question provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851461/better-git-add-p) is not at all satisfactory : (

Comment: Sounds useful.  Even more so if discarding were possible from git gui.  Btw, both "here"s link to the same question.

Comment: The UI for editing a hunk in `checkout -p` is complex enough to handle as it is. I can't imagine editing a three way patch and (a) getting it to apply and (b) getting it to do what I intended.

Comment: @CharlesBailey not a three pay path only decide if you want to Checkout (discard) or Add (stage)... in one command...

Comment: Yes, but what would the format for "edit" look like?

Comment: @CharlesBailey, the same as "checkout -p" or "add -p" ? taking it further (maybe too much, I don't know the internal workings of the diff) maybe add another character (like "i") to just ignore the change (neither delete nor add, and leave the change unstaged)

Answer (score 1):

There is no native git command that can do both. Although I do think that a better command-line hunk manager would be very useful in the git community. You should include `git reset -p` in your question as well, it's quite handy.

Comment: I would as I don't see it easy and I don't know enough about GIT... I guess it would be pretty easy to do for current GIT maintainers...

In fact, it has been proposed *some years ago*, but apparently was rejected because it was to dangerous (WTF?!). The url is not at hand at the moment.